# FCM number of users

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is FCM good for app with 100k+ users?

FCM documents say that for each sender ID, FCM allows 1000 connections in parallel. So this means that if my project has 100k+ users, I should not use FCM?

Please recommend good alternatives, if it is true. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

FCM can support any number of users, all the documentation is saying is that you can send a maximum of 1000 notifications in a single request.

Also what you are talking about is the XMPP section of FCM, you do not need to use XMPP

Comment: this means I have to notify 2000 users about something. I will notify them in 2 batches?  @tyczj

Answer (score 1):

1000 connections in parallel means in one batch you can add at most 1000 devices(their ids). Since you have 100k+ users, split them into batches of 1000, and send the request consecutively. Or you can send them concurrently if you setup multiple http connections.

Comment: Can we send batches in parallel?